# iOS: Is it possible to get the specific time zone name?

Tags: ios, timezone

I my app, I am reading time zone by

[[NSTimeZone] localizedName]

It works for most of the cases. However the iOS the one displayed is not necessarily the one read from settings. For example, if we set time zone to "Phoenix, U.S.A.", when we read it, it's "Mountain Standard Time".

The question is: Is there a way to get the display time zone name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [NSTimeZone isDaylightSavingTime] can be used to differentiate the 2 time zones.